# get focus on first form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms form1 and form2. I navigate to form2 using a button in form1. In form2 I have a button control; on button click, I show messageBox. when messageBox comes then it also lost focus of form1 but I want that it should not lost focus of form1. I have no concern with form2.

Comment: dear use form1.BringToFront()

Comment: So when user clicks that button on form2, it will show a messagebox. When messagebox is closed form1 should be shown and form2 closed?

Comment: @Developerzzz find no option form1.BringToFront()

Comment: @Mino I am not closing forms. just opening new form2 from form1 and want that when I return to form1 its fields should be enabled but all the form1 is disabled due to messageBox. Its kind of need

Comment: dear you have to create form1 object then you will find the form1.Bringtofront()

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way a message box doesn't show like a dialog. Like Eliran Pe'er said, you should make a Form like a messagebox with a label and a button and use it like this.

```
MessageForm form = new MessageForm.Show();
```

If you use ShowDialog it's going to be the same thing as MessageBox.

In your form 1 you can use `TopMost property = true` in order to keep it in front all the time no matter what. But this is going to keep your form on top of all other open programs.

Another workaround would be after messagebox is closed by the user (this is not a bad option) you can call form 1 to BringToFront(). To do this, you can pass the instance of form1 to the form2 in the Show method. Use that parameter in your form2 constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to prevent MessageBox from taking focus, and thats because a MessageBox is a dialog. (dialogs take focus from the program until they being closed)

The only way I can think of is creating new form that looks like a MessageBox, and using it instead.

Comment: yes, MessageBox is a Modal window which holds focus till closed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    if(MessageBox.Show("something")==DialogResult.OK)
    {
      form1.Focus();
    }
```

Or

```
if(MessageBox.Show("something")==DialogResult.OK)
{
  form1.Select();
}
```

Comment: no options that you told. I checked this but still not working.Form1.ActiveForm.Activate(); Form1.ActiveForm.Select(); Form1.ActiveForm.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ShowDialog() method or Show() method to show your form2?
If you are using ShowDialog() method, modify it as Show().
Because ShowDialog() method will not allow you to change the focus to main form (form1), until you close the sub form (form2)

Make sure you are using method,

```
form2.Show()
```

to Display form2.